# Issue properly comparing strings in intel assembly

Tags: arrays, string, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

My goal is to ***compare two strings***. If they are equal continue the program. If not equal, branch somewhere else. If I'm not at the end of the string and so far everything is equal, loop over to next character.

I am using visual studio, inline intel asm.

The program is functioning, although, on its first run-through, ***it takes the NOTSAME branch and proceeds to end the program, even though the strings being compared are the same.*** It does not loop at all because of this, which means something is going wrong in the comparison.

I have tried debugging it and seemingly the registers hold the correct address. Incrementing/decrementing it seems to work, from my understanding, incrementing it just moves the pointer one byte forward, pointing towards the next character. I don't really have a clear idea of which part is going wrong, I just know it isn't getting compared in how I planned.

```
int main()
{
    string arr[] = {"a","b","c","d","e" };

    string a= "a";

__asm
    {

        lea esi, arr // load address into esi
        lea edi, a
        dec edi

        LOOPING:
        inc edi// ds:di->next character in string2
        lodsb// load al with next char from string, lodsb increments si automatically.
        cmp[edi], al//; compare characters
        jne NOTSAME//; jump out of loop if they are not the same
        cmp al, 0//; they are the same, but end of string ?
        jne LOOPING//; no - so go round loop again
```

After some more debugging, it seems AL is not taking the correct byte from the string. Not sure why yet.

Comment: At first sight your code seems to look OK. But you provided only part of the relevant code. Can you provide more context (code)?

Comment: @zx485 Sorry, I added the variables to make it more readable. I didn't include code under because the third line from bottom(jne NOTSAME) is always taken, regardless of the arguments.

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant, but doesn't `string arr[]` create an array of strings and not chars? ATM I do not know how the "string" type is realized as a byte sequence. So a suggestion: have a look at the byte sequences created by the data definitions.

Comment: @zx485 I do not fully understand what you mean by byte sequences created by data definitions. I checked what the pointers are pointing to and found the data of the strings(which I changed to something longer than "a", to make it easier to spot).  It got me thinking edi is a pointer towards a string, I want to access the first byte from that string so I use [edi]. Does [edi] show me one byte or two because edi is a 32-bit register? I tried changing from cmp [edi],al to cmp byte ptr [edi],al but still no luck.

Comment: @zx485 thank you for your help. My understanding of this stuff is greatly increasing. I have an idea of what direction I should be looking into fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason, LEA stored the address 4 bytes before where the string starts. I am unsure why this is, but to fix it, I added 4 bytes to each register(pointers) and they both adjusted and now compare properly.
Changed the following

```
lea esi, a// load address into esi
lea edi,arr
add edi,4
add esi,4
```

Comment: That's probably because you have C++ `std::string` objects, not just `char*`.  The string data is only inline as part of the object for short strings, which use a union between inline data vs. pointers.  Unless that all made sense to you, and you understand why you won't find `b` at `[edi+1]`, I'd suggest sticking to C strings and `char []` (LEA to get the address of the chars) or `char*` (MOV load to get the address of the chars).